# Display inserted data in a table after inserting into Database using c# Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need when user will submit data and after it will submitted successfully those data will display in a table.

Here is my code:

`mission.aspx`:

```
<div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile">
  <label for="heading" accesskey="T">
    <span class="required">*</span> Heading
  </label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  size="30" value="" ></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
           ErrorMessage="have to fill at least 1 field"
           ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
           ClientValidationFunction="doCustomValidate"
           ValidateEmptyText="true" ></asp:CustomValidator>
  <label for="insertimage" accesskey="B">
    <span class="required">*</span> Insert Image
  </label>
  <asp:FileUpload runat="server" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="insertimage" id="insertimage" />
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server"
          ErrorMessage="have to fill at least 1 field"
          ControlToValidate="insertimage"
          ClientValidationFunction="doCustomValidate"
          ValidateEmptyText="true" ></asp:CustomValidator>
  <label for="bannerimage" accesskey="V">
    <span class="required">*</span> View Image
  </label>
  <div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    <img src="images/resource/me.jpg" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="description" accesskey="D">
    <span class="required">*</span> Description
  </label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" name="description" cols="40" multi="" Rows="7" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server"
           ErrorMessage="have to fill at least 1 field"
           ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
           ClientValidationFunction="doCustomValidate"
           ValidateEmptyText="true" ></asp:CustomValidator>
  <asp:Button  runat="server" Text="Submit" class="submit" id="submit" onclick="submit_Click" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl. No</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mission</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`mission.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BusinessObject;
using BusinessLogic;
namespace ODIYA_Doctor_Admin
{
    public partial class missionvision : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            missionBO objMissionBo = new missionBO();
            objMissionBo.heading = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
            if (insertimage.HasFile)
            {
                int length = insertimage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];
                HttpPostedFile img = insertimage.PostedFile;
                img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);
                objMissionBo.image = imgbyte;

            }
            objMissionBo.description = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
            missionvissionBL objMissionBL = new missionvissionBL();
            string action = "insert";
            var result = objMissionBL.insertMissionData(objMissionBo,action);
            if (result == 1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Alert", "Data has been Inserted", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Alert", "Data could not inserted", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`missionBL.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using BusinessObject;
using DataAccess;
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    public class missionvissionBL
    {
        public int insertMissionData(missionBO objMissionBo,string action)
        {
            try
            {
                missionDL objMissionDL = new missionDL();
                int result = 0;
                if (action == "insert")
                {
                    result = objMissionDL.insertMissionData(objMissionBo, action);
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`missionDL.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using BusinessObject;
using GenClassLibrary;
namespace DataAccess
{
   public class missionDL
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CmVar.convar);
        GenClass ob = new GenClass();
        public int insertMissionData(missionBO objMissionBo,string action)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("odMissionVission", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heading", objMissionBo.heading);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", objMissionBo.description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", objMissionBo.image);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatementType", action);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int Result = (int)cmd.Parameters["@flag"].Value;
                cmd.Dispose();
                return Result;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using 3-tier architecture in c# ASP.NET.
I would like to retrieve data from DB and add in table.

Comment: which table? and this code only inserts record, what you tried for display? I can't write complete code for you. Paste your effort and I will correct that

Comment: @ Imadoddin :Can you please give the idea or write only for one value only.

Comment: What I understood, you just inserted record in database and want to show that in gridview? Am I right?

Comment: @Imadoddin : Yes you can see there is a table i have defined in post.I need to display there.

Comment: You want to display only just inserted data or all data that is previously inserted?

Comment: @Imadoddin : If database table has some data previously it will display on that table from the beginning but user will  insert the new data it will just add in that table only.

Comment: Did the best I could to make it understandable/readable

Answer (score 0):

OK.

I would suggest you to replace your table with `GridView` for simplicity

and

Just after you insert record, write this code in `aspx.cs` file just below insertion code

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Your-Connection-string-here"))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from your-table", con)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        your-grid.DataSourse = null;
        your-grid.DataSourse = dt;
        your-grid.DataBind();
```

as you are using N-Tier, you can put this code in separate layer and call it in aspx.cs

For inserting image in database [refer this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-save-insert-Image-in-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) and to retrieve that [refer this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx)

Comment: Can i customize gridview according to my table.?

Comment: @ Imadoddin: Ok..i did this but inside that gridview i am getting the imagepath but i need to display image using that path in that particular place how i will do that.

Comment: Its very simple task. I am leaving office for the day. you try to search. If you dont find then I will solve it for you tomorrow